# sudo apt-get update problem (docker on Vagrant)

Tags: apt, updates, docker, vagrant

```
Get:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease [48.9 kB]
Ign:2 https://dowload.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Err:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7EA0A9C3F273FCD8
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:5 https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian binary/ InRelease
Ign:2 https://dowload.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Err:2 https://dowload.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease
  Could not resolve 'dowload.docker.com'
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu jammy InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7EA0A9C3F273FCD8
```

Comment: One problem is that you misspelled 'download'. You typed 'dowload' - it's missing the 'n'.